# How to get the max value in a nested list?

Tags: python, list, max

Im trying to get the `MAX` price for every 'country' in this list.

```
my_list = [
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0),'0,012'], 
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0),'0,153'], 
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,114'],
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,109'],
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,252'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,012'], 
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,113'], 
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,116'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,250'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,266'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,112'], 
    ['Italy', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,025'], 
    ['Italy', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,224'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,256'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,245']]
```

This is my code:

```
  max_price_per_list = []
  for lst in my_list:
      for price in lst:
          max_value = price[-1]
          max_price_per_list.append(max_value)
  print(max_price_per_list)
```

I received the following error: `TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable`

I expected the following outcome when I printend `max_price_per_list`:

```
['0,252', '0,266', '0,256']
```

Comment: Do you really need `for price in lst:`?

Comment: @shahkalpesh Im not so sure...

Comment: Is the list sorted by country?

Comment: @schwobaseggl no

Comment: This is the second time I've seen this list on SO and I think you're making things hard for yourself. think you should fix your data format if you're going to be doing these operations on it.  i.e. split it out into one list per country.  Or put it into a Pandas dataframe (or a relational database)

Comment: @JeffUK Well it actually is 1 big list and I need to do alot of calculations on it. Is there a possiblity to speak to you on private chat to explain it?

Comment: A sidenote: note that all your "price" values are of type string. You might want to convert them to floats before you go on. On this particular example it will not hurt you, but I think it is good practice to convert them to numbers if you treat them like numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import datetime

my_list = [
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0),'0,012'], 
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0),'0,153'], 
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,114'],
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,109'],
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,252'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,012'], 
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,113'], 
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,116'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,250'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,266'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,112'], 
    ['Italy', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,025'], 
    ['Italy', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,224'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,256'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,245']]

max_prices_by_country = {}

for item in my_list:
    price = max_prices_by_country.setdefault(item[0], 0)
    max_prices_by_country[item[0]] = max(price, float(item[-1].replace(',', '.')))

max_price_per_list = [str(price).replace('.', ',') for price in max_prices_by_country.values()]
print(max_price_per_list)
```

Comment: can you tell what you did line by line?

Comment: I've used a dict to isolate the country by the dict key. For each line depending on the country, I compute the max between the previous value (or 0 if no value was set) and the current (I also replace ',' by '.' and cast to float for comparisons in max function). Then a just keep the values of the dict but replacing back the '.' by ',' after casting to string.

Answer (score 2):

You can omit the second loop to obtain the list that you want.

```
max_price_per_list = []
for lst in my_list:
    max_value = lst[-1]
    max_price_per_list.append(max_value)
print(max_price_per_list)
```

However, if you want to get the max value per country I would recommend using the `pandas` package. You can use the code below to get the maximum price for every country in the list:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list)
df.groupby(0).max()

>>>            1          2      3
    0                                     
    Italy    Fish 2020-11-17  0,256
    Morocco  Fish 2020-11-17  0,252
    Spain    Fish 2020-11-17  0,266
```

Comment: this is not giving me the same output as I said in my question. I think its giving me the max value per list, whilst I need it per country....

Comment: the first part just shows how to get rid of the error you get, in the second part you get the max value per country using `pandas`.

Comment: If I try your second on a different dataset I get very weird values, no maximum values.

Comment: Probably because the order of your columns is different. I use `groupby` method on the first column. It may also help to convert your prices to floats, they are now stored as strings.

Answer (score 2):

> Im trying to get the MAX price for every 'country' in this list.

see below

```
import datetime
from collections import defaultdict

my_list = [
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,012'],
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,153'],
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,114'],
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,109'],
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,252'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,012'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,113'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,116'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,250'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,266'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,112'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,025'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,224'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,256'],
    ['Italy', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,245']]

data = defaultdict(float)
for country in my_list:
    price = float(country[-1].replace(',', '.'))
    if price > data[country[0]]:
        data[country[0]] = price
print(data)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'float'>, {'Morocco': 0.252, 'Spain': 0.266, 'Italy': 0.256})
```

Comment: Why `_collections` and not `collections` ?

Comment: It's a typo. Ignore it (fixed)

Comment: Perhaps in OP's locale, replacing `,` with `.` is not necessary, or perhaps not appropriate. You might want to mention that in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the nest for loop.

you can create a dict which contains country as key and max value as value.

```
country_max={}
for lst in my_list:
    if lst[0] in country_max.keys(): 
        if country_max[lst[0]]<lst[-1]:
            country_max[lst[0]]=lst[-1]
    else:
        country_max[lst[0]]=lst[-1]
print([v for _,v in country_max.items()])
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
  max_price_per_list = []
  for lst in my_list:
      max_value = lst[-1]
      max_price_per_list.append(max_value)
  print(max_price_per_list)
```

So only one for-loop.

What you are doing: with the first for-loop you are looping over the lists in your list. With the second for-loop you are looping over the single items in that list. Then you are taking the last element of that item. Since strings are iterables you can do `'Morocco'[-1]` which will return `o` since that is the last item of the string.
However, a datetime object does not allow subscripting. i.e. you cannot do `[-1]` on a datetime object. This is why it only crashes with the datetime object and not with the string objects.